# Why value in the frame than is equal to a specific size doesn't do the same job when I change the orientation of the device?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a piece of code that allows me to change the size of an `UIImageView` during the change of the orientation of the device.

I hardcoded this values (height = 896 and width = 414), and it works well, but when I want to do a dynamic size by putting the dynamic values (`height = self.view.frame.size.height` and `width = self.view.frame.size.width`), it doesn't work...

However, `self.view.frame.size.height` = 896 and `self.view.frame.size.width` = 414 this is strange... I missed something I think.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
        self.newImageView?.frame.size.height = 414
        self.newImageView?.frame.size.width = 896
        navBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 896, height: 100)
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        self.newImageView?.frame.size.height = 896
        self.newImageView?.frame.size.width = 414
        navBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 414, height: 100)
    }
}
```

**EDIT (Solution)**:
For info, I used that way for my code, but the solution in the ticket is shorter and more modern

```
 //Share bar
        let shareBar: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem:.action, target: self, action: #selector(userDidTapShare))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareBar
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            let width =  max(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
            let height = min(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
            self.newImageView?.frame.size.height = height
            self.newImageView?.frame.size.width = width
            navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: width, height: 100))
        } else {
            let width =  min(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
            let height = max(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
            self.newImageView?.frame.size.height = height
            self.newImageView?.frame.size.width = width
            navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: width, height: 100))
        }
        view.addSubview(navBar!)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use constraints and let auto-layout handle the sizing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize the navbar

```
 self.navBar.autoresizingMask = (UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.RawValue(UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleRightMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleLeftMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleBottomMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleTopMargin.rawValue))))
```

put this after your view.addSubview(navBar!)

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in that method and you will see that this method is called before the view changes the orientation, this is why you don't the proper height and width, use the values inside the size parameter instead, this should work.

But agree with the comments, use auto-layout instead, it will make your life easier